User group permission queries
I've been exploring user permissions while defining user groups, but I'm unclear on the purpose of the following permissions:

Lock

Unlock Always

Add Version

Create Draft

Create Discussion


Is there a blog or does anyone have a detailed explanation for these permissions? Specifically, I want to understand what actions a user can perform or expect to see if these permissions are assigned to their user group.

Below are the details on the operations allowed when these permissions are enabled in Content Hub.

Add Version: This permission will allow you to create different version of the content for the same language in Content Hub CMP module. You can restore to any version at any particular time.



Create Draft: This permission comes in role when you enable draft functionality on the schema. This lets you reuse one content item as a base and create/modify the new entity(created from original) without changing the original entity. This draft then can be approved/rejected to modify the original entity.

Lock: This permission provide the ability to user to lock the entities in content hub in order to prevent further modifications on the entity.

UnlockAlways: This permission is used in those case where you would like to override the locking behaviour and have the entities displayed as unlocked to the user always.

Create Discussion: This allows you to create comments on entity details pages.



Note: Both the Lock and UnlockAlways permission are used for drafts feature. When a draft is created, original entity gets locked and once the draft is approved/rejected, original entity is unlocked and draft is deleted.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.
